# do I get rep when someone upvotes my comments?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

When people upvote my comments, am I supposed to gain reputation from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In short, no](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

You only get reputation from having your questions & answers voted for, and accepting answers on your own questions.